# Jquery form submit with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, form-submit

I need help with what I thought would be a simple form submit problem with Jquery, but am running into issues.

I have a form, #listing_step_1, in which the user first selects a category from a dropdown.  When a category has been selected, if the user clicks "next", the subcategory dropdown is revealed.  When both a category and subcategory is selected, clicking next will take them to step 2 of the process using a redirect.  On submission, the form is reloading the same page using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

I want to autosubmit the form so clicking on next is not required to reveal the subcategories. I'm trying to do this on an onchange event using JQuery, but the following code does not work.

```
$('#item_category').change(function(){
   $('#listing_step_1').submit();
});
```

I would appreciate any help with this as I am new to form submission using JQuery and AJAX. Manually, it's working fine - i.e., pressing the page button and with the PHP page refresh. I thought by simply submitting the form in the onchange instance it would reload and execute the required actions, but this does not appear to be the case.

Form code:

```
<form method="post" name="listing_step_1" id="listing_step_1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php if($errormessage != ""){ echo ' style="margin-top: 30px"';}?>>
  <div class="formField fullwidth">
    <label for="item_category">Category *</label>
    <select id="item_category" name="item_category">
      <option value="0">Select category...</option>
      <?php $cd = new CategoryListing("<option_credits>", "</option>"); ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="formField fullwidth">
    <label for="item_subcategory">Subcategory*</label>
    <?php if($dropdownlist != "") { ?>
    <select id="item_subcategory" name="item_subcategory">
      <?php echo $dropdownlist; ?>
    </select>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <select id="item_subcategory" name="item_subcategory" disabled="true">
      <option value="0">Select subcategory...</option>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submit" name="submit" style="width: 100px;" />
</form>
```

Form Submission:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if($_POST['item_category'] != 0){
  $dropdownlist = CategoryListing::getSubCategoryDropdown($_POST['item_category']);
 } 
 else {
  $errormessage = "Please select a category";
 }
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#item_category').change(function(){
      this.form.submit();
     });
});
```

Comment: Show more of your code including the HTML elements that make up your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
  $('#item_category').change(function(){
     this.form.submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: The form still doesn't appear to submit with

$('#item_category').change(function(){
   this.form.submit();
});

Comment: @pingu - Would help if you could post the html of the form as well

Comment: @pingu - Make sure the code is wrapped in a document.ready call...I've updated the answer to this, was that already the case?

Comment: Try plan B:  `$('#item_category').change(function(){ $("#submit").click(); });`

Comment: That works! Any logical reason why plan B works and A doesn't?

Comment: There must be something else in the form...or it's bed time here and I'm just missing the obvious...which is entirely possible.  Some form submit behavior is wacky in the browser if any html is off/invalid as well...that may be the case once it's full rendered, check out the W3C Validator to see if that could be a contributing factor: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

in your description, you say:

> I have a form, #listing_stage_1, in
>   which the user first selects a c...

then in code you say:

```
$('#item_category').change(function(){
   $('#listing_step_1').submit();
});
```

I imagine you are just using the wrong selector... change your code to this:

```
$('#item_category').change(function(){
   $('#listing_stage_1').submit();
});
```

Comment: sorry they should both be step - not stage. Edited.